# ¿Por que marca este error en el uso de la función ->fetch_all()? Al estar el sitio en un hosting, localmente funciona

Tags: php, mysqli

Es una función de un archivo externo que contiene una consulta multi-tabla, la mando a traer desde el formulario del otro archivo e imprimo sus valores que genera el array númerico resultado de la consulta, con la función `->fetch_all()` . Pero resulta que en servidor local de mi máquina funciona, pero al subir los archivos a un hosting, marca este error, siendo que de manera local no lo marca: Error en la función,

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all()

```php
function getAlumByGpoMat2($conexion,$grupos)
{
   $respuesta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT A.matricula, A.nombre, AG.parcial1, AG.inasisP1, AG.parcial2, AG.inasisP2, AG.final, AG.idAlumno, AG.parcial3, AG.inasisP3, AG.idGrupo, AG.final, AG.asistencias FROM alumno A, alumno_grupo AG, materias M, periodos Pr, profesores P, grupos G WHERE M.idMateria = G.materia and A.idAlumno = AG.idAlumno and G.idGrupo = AG.idGrupo and G.profesor = P.idProfesor and G.periodo = Pr.idPeriodo and AG.idGrupo = $grupos ORDER BY A.nombre") or die (mysqli_error($conexion)); 

       return $respuesta->fetch_all(); 

}
```

```php
 if(isset($_GET['gpo']))  

      $grupos = $_GET['gpo'];  //RECIBIMOS EL PARAMETRO POR URL : EL ID DE LA TABLA ALUMNO_GRUPO

       $alumbosByGpoMater = getAlumByGpoMat2($conexion,$grupos); //funcion extraida del archivo externo

<form method="POST" action="capt_cambios.php">
        <?php
        //listado de los alumnos del grupo que estan en esa materia:
         foreach ($alumbosByGpoMater as $alumno): 
        ?>
        <tr>    
           <!-- imprime contador de registros, o numero de registros que aparecen recuperados  -->
          <td><?php if ($i <= $num_rows) {  echo $i; } ?></td>
          <!-- imprime matrticula de alumno  -->
          <td><?php echo $alumno[0];?></td>
          <!-- imprime nombre de alumno  -->
          <td><?php echo $alumno[1];?></td>
          <!-- casillas para capturar caliicaciones  e inasistencias por periodo  -->
          <!-- parcialP1= calificacion periodo e inasistencias del periodo 1  -->
          <!-- intentaba enviar un solo arreglo con ambas columnas: calificacion e inasistencias por periodo  -->
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP1[]" class="p1" size="2" value="<?php echo $alumno[2]; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP1[]" class="p1" size="2" value="<?php echo $alumno[3]; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP2[]" class="p2" size="2" value="<?php echo $alumno[4]; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP2[]" class="p2" size="2" value="<?php echo $alumno[5]; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP3[]" class="p3" size="2" value="<?php echo $alumno[8]; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP3[]" class="p3" size="2" value="<?php echo $alumno[9]; ?>" ></td>

          <td><input type="hidden" name="idgpo[]" value="<?php echo $alumno[10]; ?>" readonly></td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="idalumno[]" value="<?php echo $alumno[7]; ?>" readonly></td>

          <td><input type="text" name="final[]" class="final" size="2" value="<?php echo $alumno[11]; ?>" readonly ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="porcent[]" class="porcent" size="2" value="<?php echo $alumno[12]; ?>" readonly ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="asistotales[]" class="inatot" size="2" value="" ></td>
       <?php 
          $i++;  //incrementamos contador en 1 luego de cada alumno recuperado, 
          endforeach 
        ?> 
         <td><input type="text" name="numsesiones" class="nsesiones" size="2" value="" ></td>
        </tr>
            </tbody>
           </table>
           <div align="center">    
           <button type="submit" name="formAlumno" id="enviar" class="btn btn-success">CAPTURAR EVALUACIONES</button>
           </div>
           </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: la probe sustituyendo en la función, por return $res = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta, MYSQLI_NUM); Pero no esta imprimiendo lo que returna la función. El hosting gratuto que probaba era 5.5

Answer (score 1):

Mira a ver cual es la versión de tu servidor. Posiblemente el problema sea porque la versión en la que la función [`fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) empieza a estar soportada es la versión de `PHP 5.3.0`.

Podrías usar el método [`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) en su defecto, ya que este si que está soportado para versiones anteriores, de la siguiente manera:

```
$filas= array();
while ($fila = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $filas[] = $fila;
}
```

De esta manera estarías simulando el  efecto que hace el método `fetch_all`.

---

Por otro lado, como me has comentado que tu versión es mayor a la `5.3.0`, entonces en teoría no tendrías que tener ningún problema con esta función respecto a la versión del PHP del servidor.

Sin embargo, tendrías que comprobar que tengas instalado el paquete `mysqlnd`, tal y como indica en la **[documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-all-mysqlnd)**, ya que sino no te funcionará.

> Disponible sólo con **mysqlnd**.

Comment: si es lo que acabo de ver, en el servidor de local de la maquina es 5.6 el del hosting es 5.5

Comment: @ArmandoArellano Acabo de ver en la documentación de [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) que se requiere el paquete `mysqlnd` instalado en tu servidor. _Available only with mysqlnd._ Mira a ver si tienes este paquete instalado.

Comment: es un hosting gratuto el que tiene version 5.5,, voy a ver si hay modo de revisarlo

Comment: @ArmandoArellano Si no siempre puedes simular el efecto utilizando `fetch_assoc` como te he puesto en la repuesta ya que este no necesita ningún tipo de paquete.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Sí, por supuesto. Ya está agregado.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable es que la versión de php de tu hosting sea vieja. El método fetch_all() funciona desde [PHP 5.3.0](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php#88031).

`fetch_assoc()` podria servir.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

esto me soluciono mysqlnd o nd_mysqli (así me apareció a mi), entré en configuración php , y seleccione esa extensión, actualice y solucionado. uso version 5.6.

Importante si aun usas mysql, te aparecerá también nd_mysql . Solo activa la que uses, te recomiendo que te pases a mysqli.

Comment: Bienvenido!! podrias mirar el [tour] y tambien [answer]. Tene en cuenta que la pregunta es muy vieja, y aunque tu respuesta puede ser correcta, puede que en ese momento no lo fuera.