# ¿Cuál es una función equivalente a ->fetch_all(), para usar en función que al ser llamada devuelva el arreglo de datos.?

Tags: php, mysqli

Hace rato no encontraba el error, ya lo encontré:
Estoy intentando imprimir los datos traidos de una función que devuelve un array, `fetch_all()` El error lo manda en el archivo: `error_log` y es: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all() in /home/platafo6/public_html/Model/Model_Depto.php on line 363

Localmente tenia la versión php: 5.6.15 instalada ahi funcionaba todo bien, la versión del servidor web es 5.6. ¿Por cuál función debería cambiarla? De manera que en otro archivo, reciba la función e imprima sus datos en foreach. Ya lo tenía pero no me detecta la función en el servidor.

```js
function getAlumByGpoMat2($conexion,$grupos)
{
   $respuesta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT A.matricula, A.nombre, AG.parcial1, AG.inasisP1, AG.parcial2, AG.inasisP2, AG.final, AG.idAlumno, AG.parcial3, AG.inasisP3, AG.idGrupo, AG.final, AG.asistencias FROM alumno A, alumno_grupo AG, materias M, periodos Pr, profesores P, grupos G WHERE M.idMateria = G.materia and A.idAlumno = AG.idAlumno and G.idGrupo = AG.idGrupo and G.profesor = P.idProfesor and G.periodo = Pr.idPeriodo and AG.idGrupo = $grupos ORDER BY A.nombre") or die (mysqli_error($conexion)); 

       return $respuesta->fetch_all(); //363 LINEA DE ERROR

}
```

Comment: puedes ver estas respuestas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664536/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-resultfetch-all Si alguna te sirve puedes responder a tu pregunta aqui, seguro ganas una medalla de [autodidacta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner)

Comment: gracias, saludos

Comment: Ya te han respondido antes a esta pregunta [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/39076/16597)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesita que el driver mysqlnd antes de poder usarlo. Si usas Debian o Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

Posiblemente tengas que activar el modulo:

```
sudo php5enmod mysqlnd
```

Luego reinicia tu servicio.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: gracias, buscaré la terminal

Comment: @ArmandoArellano cuenta luego si haz solucionado o si seguís con el problema.

Comment: si ya quedo instalada, gracias

Comment: @ArmandoArellano por nada.

Comment: que tal, y si ya esta instalado el driver pero sigue sin detectar la funcion:
 ->fetch_all() ?

Comment: @ArmandoArellano seguramente tengas que activar el modulo. En la respuesta de arriba agregue algunas cosas.

Comment: supuestamente de manera gráfica ya esta instalado, pero voy a ver la manera de ingresar a  la terminal

Comment: No tengo acceso a la terminal por el tipo de contrato, pero el error que me arroja es el siguiente: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all()